# How to rename a node with Python LXML?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, lxml.html

How do I rename a node using LXML?

Specifically, how to rename a parent  node i.e. a `<body>` tag while preserving all the underlying structure?

I am parsing using the `lxml.html` module but supposedly there shouldn't be any difference between xml and html in terms of renaming between `lxml.html.HtmlElement` and its XML counterpart.

I have searched through the docs at the [LXML](http://lxml.de/) site but didn't find any reference to renaming of nodes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you have the `<body>` element, just change its `tag` attribute.

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.fromstring("<html><body><p></body></html>")
body = doc.find('body')
body.tag = "body-not"
print(lxml.etree.tostring(doc))
```

This prints

```
b'<html><body-not><p/></body-not></html>'
```